# Ajax post request- Unresolvable dependency resolving and error 500

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a multi-step form using jQuery anad AJAX. But Im getting this error when "go to step 2" is clicked:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Also when clicking in network tab and then click in "storeUserInfo" it appears:

```
exception
:
"Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException"
file
:
"/Users/jakeB/projects/store/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
line
:
933
message
:
"Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> array $data ]] in class Illuminate\Validation\Validator"
```

Do you know where is the error?

In the PaymentController there is the storeUserInfo() Method that is the method for the step 1:

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'buyer_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_email' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'name_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'country_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            if($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('test');
            }

            $this->throwValidationException(

                $request, $validator
            );
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);
```

// step 1 and step 2 html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix tabs hide" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <form method="post">
            <h6>Payment method</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentmethod1" value="option1" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">payment method 1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="credit_card" value="option1">
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">Stripe</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary prev-step">
                Go back to step 2
            </button>
            <button type="button"  data-nexttab="#step3" href="#step3"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn ml-2 next-step">
                Go to step 3
            </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

// ajax in payment.blade.php

```
$('#goToStep2').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{    route('products.storeUserInfo',compact('id','slug') ) }}',
            data: custom_form.serialize(),
            datatype: 'json',

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                setTimeout(function () {

                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                var errorsHtml = '';
                $.each(errors['errors'], function (index, value) {
                    errorsHtml += '<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item alert alert-danger">' + value + '</li></ul>';
                });

                $('#response').show().html(errorsHtml);
            }
        });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Validator facade class in your PaymentController

```
use Validator;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

   public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'buyer_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_surname' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'buyer_email' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'name_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'country_invoice' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            if($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('test');
            }

            $this->throwValidationException(

                $request, $validator
            );
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have "use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;" in the PaymentController.

Comment: Illuminate\Validation\Validator doesn't have method make() . The code i had provided is the correct syntax for using validator. Check out this link. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Thanks, do you know why if there is  a validation error the 'test' dont appears?

Comment: Try using $request->expectsJson() . 
And put a header " Accept: application/json"  in your ajax request.

Comment: Instead of "        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[

"?

Comment: Like that it appears "{message: "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Valida…Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 221"" and ""{↵    "message": "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Validation\\Factory::make() must be of the type array, boolean given" and also "jquery.min.js:4 POST http://store.test/product/1/product-test/payment/storeUserInfo 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: With "        $validator = Validator::make($request->expectsJson(),[".

Comment: Instead of $request->ajax() use $request->expectsJson()

Comment: Thanks, like that if there is a validation error also the 'test' from "return response('test');" dont appears.